# How to switch case over an List<string> in C#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, switch-statement

I want to do a `switch case` over a `List<string>` in C#.

Let's say I have the following list:

```
var myList = new List<string>(new string[] { "Apple", "Pear" });
```

Now I wanna check if Apple or Pear and then do something. In an `if statement` it would look like this:

```
if (myList.Contains("Apple"))
   //do something
else if (myList.Contains("Pear"))
   //so some other thing
else
   //throw error
```

Now how can I do this in an clean way as a `switch statement`?

Comment: So if the list contains `"Apple"`, you *only* want to do the Apple-thing and *don't* want to do the Pear-thing, even if the list would also contain `"Pear"`?

Comment: And what if you have 2 Apples and an Orange?

Comment: @Corak that's correct.

Comment: @bommelding as Corak mentioned, I only wanna do the apple thingy if apple exists in the list.

Comment: @RaphaelM.- and you only want to do the Apple-thing *once*, even if there are two or three or a hundred `"Apple"` entries in the list.

Comment: @Corak exactly.

Comment: @Lucifer - that _is_ a `Contains()`. Op already does that.

Comment: @RaphaelM. - So what is (feels) wrong with your current code?  It's not going to get much better.

Comment: @bommelding boss wants it with a switch so I just wanted to ask if this is possible...

Comment: @RaphaelM. if your code is simple and working no need to make it complex by adding such complexity.

Comment: @RaphaelM.- in a `switch` you don't (can't? -- well fallthroughs... ugh...) have the logic that `"Apple"` is "prefered" to `"Pear"` -- you *could* write your own `IComparer<string>` that defines `"Apple"` as having a higher priority than `"Pear"` and then do something like `var entry = myList.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x, yourComparer).FirstOrDefault();` and then switch over the value of `entry`...

Comment: When your boss micro manages at that level then ask him/her.

Comment: One more thing, you can instantiate the list with known values directly like `var myList = new List<string>{ "Apple", "Pear" };` without the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think, your desired behaviour can be cleanly modeled with a switch. But to make it as managable and easy to add/change as possible, how about something like this:

```
var handlers = new[]
{
    new Tuple<string, Action>("Apple", () => { /* Apple-thing */ }),
    new Tuple<string, Action>("Pear", () => { /* Pear-thing */ }),
    // add as many handlers as needed in proper sequence
};

var handled = false;
foreach (var handler in handlers)
{
    if (myList.Contains(handler.Item1))
    {
        handler.Item2();
        handled = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!handled)
{
    // throw error
}
```

Comment: And this is an improvement over the original if/else ?  Wanna ask a cyclomatic analysis tool?

Comment: I'll mark your solution as right answer because it would work (not that simple code but still...). But I think I'm gonna talk to my boss to leave it with if else

Comment: This can be an improvement over a massive chain of if/else.

Comment: @bommelding - not really. It might (arguably) be easier to maintain if requirements change, like "now Pears should be handled *before* Apples" or "now do Oranges, too". -- also, this is "one" line per case instead of several.

Answer (score 9):

Stumbled across this and didn't really see anyone answer him.
It is possible to do this as a switch statement, whether or not it "looks" better can be decided by the user.

```
var myList = new List<string> { "Apple", "Pear" };
switch (myList)
{
    case var _ when myList.Contains("Apple"):
        // do apple stuff
        break;
    case var _ when myList.Contains("Pear"):
        // do pear stuff
        break;
    default:
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Some error message", nameof(myList));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
foreach (var fruit in myList)
{
    switch (fruit)
    {
        case "Apple":
            // do something
            break; // or consider return based on your requirements
        case "Pear":
            // do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But as in the if statement, I only wanna do the Apple thingy if Apple exists in the list.

Comment: If `myList` contains several `"Apple"` entries, the Apple-thing is done as many times (and not just once as OP wants). If `myList` contains `"Apple"` **and** `"Pear"`, *both* things are done (instead of *only* the Apple-thing in that case).

Comment: @Corak No, just return from the statement rather than breaking. I assume OP is capable enough to modify an example to their requirement.

Comment: @OwenPauling - even then, if `myList` contains `"Pear"` *before* `"Apple"`, you'd do the Pear-thing (and return) instead of doing the Apple-thing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to put this kind of code in a `switch`-Statement, because it's not designed for checking if some List has an element. Its designed to **switch** different values of **one** variable.

Answer (score 1):

If this is some sort of code-golf challenge where one cannot use the commands "if" or "else", and must use a "switch", one might rise to the challenge in this manner:

```
string reallyWantToUseASwitchStatement = null;
reallyWantToUseASwitchStatement = reallyWantToUseASwitchStatement ?? 
                                  (list.Contains("Apple") ? "Apple" : null);
reallyWantToUseASwitchStatement = reallyWantToUseASwitchStatement ?? 
                                  (list.Contains("Pear") ? "Pear" : null);
switch (reallyWantToUseASwitchStatement)
{
    case "Apple":
        break;
    case "Pear":
        break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

do a loop on myList and then switch the local variable.

```
        List<string> myList = new List<string>()
            { "Apple", "Pear"};

        myList.ForEach(x => 
        {
            switch (x)
            {
                case "Apple":
                {
                    //do something
                    break; 
                }
                case "Pear":
                {
                    // do something
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @
DotNetChic
 yes, considering the time stamps, leave it here. I've undone my downvote. I'd like to note often people are start writing a post and don't see the other posted answer until after they've submitted.

Comment: This does not do, what OP needs it to do. It has the exact same problems as mentioned in the comments of the answer of Owen Pauling.

Comment: It does, according to the original question. If we are going by the comments on "Owens" answer, He might need to use MyList.Contains("Apple")  rather than a switch IMO

Comment: It doesn't. The `if`/`else if` code in the original question clearly shows what behaviour is expected. If `myList` contains (at least) one entry `"Apple"`, the Apple-thing should be executed **and nothing else**. Your code will execute the Apple-thing **and also** the Pear-thing. Also, the Apple thing (or the Pear-thing respectively) should only be executed **exactly once**. Your code executes them as many times as those entries exist in the list. And also, if the list contains neither `"Apple"`, nor `"Pear"`, an error should be thrown, which you code doesn't.